# Declaring PHP variables with numbers (based on loop and based on num of records returned by a query)

Tags: php, mysql, loops, variables

I have this on the first page: 
returned results
[image]

it shows 2 groups with different ID and with different number of members. IT09 has 3 and IT10 has 4.
when the "Evaluate" label is clicked, the page then proceeds here.

[image]

Those textboxes are declared in such a way like this:

```
<table>
$i=1;
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($querys))
{
echo '<tr>
<td width="120">'.$data['thenames'].'</td>
<td width="50">
<input type="text" name="newSG'.$i.'" id="newSG'.$i.'" class="evaluation" value="'.$data[$toshow].'" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
</td>
<td>
<input type="hidden" name="stud'.$i.'" id="stud'.$i.'" value="'.$data['memberID'].'" />
</td>
</tr>';
$i++;
}
</table>
```

As you can see, it creates a textbox and a hidden input with name and id with a number at the end. That's what i also want to happen on my php part.

I have this code

```
$ii = 1;
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
$stud(here) = $_POST['stud'(and here)]; <<<<

$ii++
}
```

I want to declare variables using this loop . as you can see (here , andhere) I want that to have numbers 1,2,3 or depending on the number of records returned by my query. the problem here is that I want to declare something like $stud1, $stud2 and so on. I dont know how to add the value of the loop after the variable $stud. can someone help?

Comment: yah yah yah that's my problem. can you give me an example of a syntax where the variable is concatenated with the number ?

Comment: Don't use variable variables. Just use an array.

Comment: @Rizier123 Don't help him do the wrong thing.

Comment: @Barmar You're right. If this would be the only wrong thing(`mysql_*`).

Comment: @Rizier123 that's what i did earlier, its wrong.

Comment: @barmar i cant simpy do that since the the number of variables i should declare depends on the number of records my query returns. so i suppose i should use a loop rather than array right? or can u help me with this?

Comment: @PatrickJohnCalumno Show us a bit more context how and for what you need the data, so we can show you how you can do it right.

Comment: @PatrickJohnCalumno That's the point of using arrays. You don't have to know how many there are.

Answer (score 1):

make an associative array instead.

`$studs = array();
while(...){
    $studs['stud'.index] = $row;
}`

access it :

`echo $studs['stud1'][field];`

if you really want it as a variable then:

`eval('return $stud'.$ii.'=json_decode(\''.json_encode($row).'\');');`

then you can:

`echo $stud1->field;`

Edit:

it seems your assigning your stud variable with the post. then you can:

`eval('return $stud'.$ii.'=$_POST[\''.$ii.'\']');`

access it:

`echo $stud1;`

Comment: im finding it a bit hard to understand, shoud I write anything inside array(here)? and the word index, should it be just that word or any index number i would need? and lastly $row, (the value) what if it's from a post method. $_POST['stud'] how should I include the number on that?

Comment: dont put anything in array() it's just declaring an array. index should be in your case the `$ii`. `$row` should be the $data in your `mysql_fetch_array`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use separate variables, use an array.

```
$studs = array();
$i = 1;
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($querys)) {
    $studs[$i] = $_POST['studs' . $i];
}
```

I'm not sure why you're filling in a variable from POST data in a loop over database results, but that's not really relevant.

I also suggest that you take `$i` out of the form inputs. Give them names like `studs[]` and `newSG[]`, and PHP will automatically put them into an array in `$_POST`. You can then do:

```
$studs = $_POST['studs'];
$newSG = $_POST['newSG'];
```

Comment: There. it's done! :) thanks @barmar. but the part that you suggest, sorry but i have my reasons why I include $i on their name values. hehe.. Thank  you so much anyway :) Happy new year